# Pulling the 5 character code from large text

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have to derive the customer code from large text columns.

The first character is either a,b,c,d.

Second character is usually numbers but sometimes people misunderstand to be letter 'o' and type in as letter 'o' or sometimes use space (Making the total chacters to be 6)

Third to Fifth character is alphanumeric.
I tried this

[ABCDabcd][Oo0-9][0-9A-Za-z]{3}|[^A-Za-z0-9][ABCDabcd]\s[Oo0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}

[image: This failed when all are alphabets]

This failed when all were alphabets were used.I wanted to remove words. But was unable to using \W or [^A-Za-z0-9]{5}. Not sure why it highlighted after hui

Comment: In the example each code is on a line by itself. Is that always the case?

Comment: No, It is normally in the paragraphs. For simplicity I showed lines

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following pattern matches best what you are looking for:

```
\b[ABCDabcd]\s?[Oo0-9][0-9A-Za-z]{3}\b
```

This will match all the codes, but unfortunately, it will also match words like `"books"` and `"code6"` but this is *By Design*, because there's nothing in your *specification* that differentiates them from actual codes.

Comment: At least is it possible to negate all alphabets is my main question at least later on in the next step

Comment: @viji What if the code is `b00ks` and the user types `books`?